# I want to zip a images from url in react js using jszip and file-saver

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, jszip

I have tried this tutorial [enter link description here](https://www.mridul.tech/blogs/how-to-generate-zip-with-file-links-in-next-js-and-react-js)

but still not able to get a images in zip folder.

```js
async function downloadResourcesOnClickTest() {
  const zip = new JSZip();

  const siteImageData = [{
      fileUrl: 'https://saseuwdevattachmentapi.blob.core.windows.net/generic-final-container/1017f445-6833-4ca5-bb4d-eec994a4c622.jpg',
      fileName: 'test_1.png'
    },
    {
      fileUrl: 'https://saseuwdevattachmentapi.blob.core.windows.net/generic-files-container/c47136a4-d323-408b-b82b-3367226272a0.jpg',
      fileName: 'test_2.png'
    }
  ];


  // Download images and add to zip file
  for (const imageData of siteImageData) {
    const response = await fetch(imageData.fileUrl);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    zip.file(imageData.fileName, blob);
  }

  // Generate and download zip file
  zip.generateAsync({
    type: 'blob'
  }).then(function(blob) {
    saveAs(blob, 'images.zip');
  });
}

Here is HTML code snippest :
```

```html
<Button variant="outlined" onClick={downloadResourcesOnClickTest}>
                DOWNLOAD PHOTOS
              </Button>
```

I am trying to fetch an image url and get a blob and create new file and save it as zip array and using file-saver want to zip it.

Comment: Does it produce any error messages on the browser's debug console? What are you getting back instead of an image? Also, could you please show us the code you're using to fetch the image?

Comment: Using `responseType: 'json'` for fetching an image is highly suspicious, since images are binary; anyway, has @Mati Ullah Zahir's answer worked?

Comment: Getting a binary file response

Comment: @Haroldo_OK its not producing an error in message. but in zip folder all images are 0kb size and not having any data

Comment: Testing your code on my computer is causing CORS errors. Are you sure there aren't any errors on the browsers console? Do any errors appear on the network tab?

Comment: Hey I have used this way added headers option no-cors and allowed-origin-access : '*'

Comment: mode: 'no-cors',
         headers: {
           'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
         },
     })

Comment: Adding those headers _client-side_ has no effect. Does the image server return 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the _response_? Those are the headers that the browser will listen to.